# Manage/disambiguate [sql] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-tips

I've seen a lot of question with only the [sql] tag, or with other tag but no one to define the specific database.

I understand that it's not possible to burninate it, but will it be possible to add a warning when posting the question or automatically add the comment that ask to define the specific database?

Comment: This is a tag clean-up request *and* a feature request all in one. Just like the main site, it is best to limit yourself to asking one question per question.

Comment: @CodyGray it's only a feature request as a tag cleaning will require a disproportionate effort, the first sentence of the second paragraph is to let everyone known that I understand that the clean-up is impossible

Comment: Possibly related to this request - [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips)

Comment: I already requested this. See ^

Comment: @Kermit your post in MSE is undeniably better then mine