# Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, asking-questions, tag-tips

After adding a particular tag, such as

<kbd>[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOGt3.png]</kbd>

this super helpful assistant will pop-up to suggest what their question should contain:

<kbd>[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQPDw.png]</kbd>

Since forcing users to get badges or asking them "[what have you tried?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)" to improve question quality isn't working, this seems like a viable alternative.

The nice thing about this is that it will allow the community to create standards (or a "tag-tip" wiki) for what each tag should say.

Comment: Did you really just invoke Clippy? (Now I'm going to start having the nightmares again.)

Comment: Upvoted for "help the helpless " - This is what we're here for. Thank You Very Much

Comment: This is the first implementation of the "show tag-based info" idea that I actually like.

Comment: This really should be a unicorn assistant, though....

Comment: Who creates/edits the tag tip wiki? Anyone? People with a certain number of answers in that tag?

Comment: At the risk of appearing too dorky even for Meta, I vote we twist Clippy into the shape of the [Angel Investigations logo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1BjAS.jpg).  (Can also be used to dust help vampires.)

Comment: Memories of [clippycorn](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3176/the-sinister-clippycorn)

Comment: @MartinSmith If this feasible, I would suggest the same rep privileges  apply for tag-tips that do for tag edits.

Comment: For clippy's sake, can this just stay closed or open?

Comment: wtf. This was reopened by 5 community members, why did it have to be closed again unilaterally? Please reopen - it is distinct from the other suggestion in that it has a concrete suggestion with a screen shot.

Comment: I'm hoping for an answer from @Shog9 along the lines of "we're working on implementing this request as we speak."

Comment: You mean this one has an image to trump the other, which lays out logic and triggers @pek

Comment: Clippy? That's ridiculous, it'll turn people off immediately. [Try this](http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090319134159/zelda/images/2/2c/Navi_Artwork.png)

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's distinct because it uses clippy and the other one didn't? I'm pretty sure that wasn't a serious part of the suggestion, but it was apparently clever enough to get a post from a year ago closed as a duplicate

Comment: Perhaps we need start a new discussion on what will be replacing clippy.

Comment: @BenBrocka Navi, clippy etc... Are you guys kidding ? You all know [what we need](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6d8ebb117e8d83d74ea95fbdd0f87e13?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)

Comment: @random it's not about clippy, it's about how also the *selection* of example tips hit the mark (unlike the other question, which otherwise is perfectly fine of course). That small difference made the suggestion fare much better than the original one... look at the votes. Not that you weren't correct in closing it, technically.

Comment: Ha Ha tat was Funny. .

Comment: This could have helped me for sure.

Comment: This is a really good proposal! I can already see the annoying `assembly` postings which really are `net-assembly` vanish like snow in the sun. :) Not really, but it may help. :)

Comment: @Pëkka that's a bold bounty :)

Comment: It seems to me that a lot of first questions are from askers who just google around, find a place where they can dump their question, and they do just that - they don't even know that there are any rules to read, etc. It's a fact of life, and the more we accept it and deal with it productively, the better SO will be.

Comment: related: [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page)

Comment: So how's the implementation coming along @Oded?

Comment: Presumably to display to users with rep below 2K or 5K, to avoid annoying nags?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Shucks, this is a pretty popular feature-request... Let's give it a try & see if it's more helpful than annoying:

[image: Questions about SQL get better answers if they...]

This'll pop up every time someone tries to ask a question with [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql). It's not context-sensitive - if they've already included everything in that list, they'll *still* get the popup. But, it doesn't stop them from submitting the question...

If we don't hate ourselves after a few weeks of this, we can give some of [Bohemian's ideas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips/274633#274633) a try in other tags...

Comment: Woot woot! But I'm disappointed there's no clippy.

Comment: Briefly tried [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eoY1u.png), then remembered I hate unicorns.

Comment: If this works out, can I get a StackOverflow pencil?

Comment: If it works out, I'll steal you a box of paperclips from the Stack Overflow office.

Comment: I love this but it would be even better if the platform text prescribed that usually they want to pick only one platform. We [still](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451745/retrieve-records-from-multiple-tables-using-join) [get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451894/need-help-developing-sql-to-find-difference-in-date) [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448676/sql-group-by-custom-range) of people tagging both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server], and in almost every single scenario it is just wrong (or maybe I have too much faith and they're over-tagging intentionally).

Comment: Changed "a" to "one", @Aaron. Doubtful it will help much, but can't hurt.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9! I doubt it will help much either, because no matter how big the spoon you're using to feed, some still refuse to eat. But like you said, can't hurt.

Comment: (Also, if you're going by popular, [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history) came up [yet again](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274776/proper-to-downvote-a-user-who-posts-the-same-answer-later-on).) :-)

Comment: Is that available on other sites, or just SO?

Comment: This particular message is only for SO, @bfavaretto

Comment: So I foresee a feature request on MSE soon :)

Comment: All such messages will be per-site, @bfavaretto - there are relatively few tags that would benefit from such guidance on *all* sites.

Comment: I thought you meant the *feature* was not available on all sites. I don't see any warning when trying to use the [sql] tag on pt.so, hence my question. That would be a nice feature to have there. Even nicer if the messages could be set and edited by moderators.

Comment: How about adding the ability for gold badge users to add something like that on a per-tag basis ;)

Comment: Related feaure-request on a different site: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1419/49.

Comment: @Shog9: You introduced a bug: [Your tags cannot be submmited: \[sql\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278362), preventing tag edits adding [tag:sql].

Comment: @Shog9 Any stats on whether this has actually helped or not?

Comment: @Shog9 So... it's been a while. If there has been no backslash, could we by any chance get this feature now for _any_ tag that needs it, in an editable manner?

Comment: @Shog does this feature exist only on Stack Overflow? Or on other sites too?

Comment: It can be done on any site, @Shadow - but only in the limited way described above (sidebar pop-up, gotta get an employee to add it).

Answer (score 43):

There are certain tips for writing good questions that new users particularly don't abide by, for which they are often chided via comments and told to edit their questions. A large percentage of comments relate only to not obeying these tips. Further, lots of questions are closed ultimately, because they don't follow such tips.

As you said, the tips vary greatly depending on the context (that is, tags) of the question. Here's a few examples:

- [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql): Include [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) tag, relevant schema, sample data and a link to an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) of same and desired output
- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java): Don't "code dump", make sure posted code compiles, create an [short, self contained, correct compilable, example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) (SSCCE)
- [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex): Post examples of text that should match and text that should not match. Post a link to an on-line regular expression tester with your sample input and attempted regular expression.

#### Suggestion:

It would be great if such tag-sensitive question-writing tips were shown to the user as they were writing their question, rather than waiting for them to write the question and then get a raft of negative comments and have to edit it. The tag data would have to have a new attribute(s) for "question tips" (possibly a child entity for many).

As tags are added to a question, a panel could appear on the right with the relevant tips with (links to) sample questions demonstrating each tip.

The information about tips would be community driven with the tag-edit being enhanced to allow experts (for example, 1000 reputation points in the tag) to edit the tips.

Certain tags would "inherit" their tips from a "parent" tag, for example, [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) and [postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgres) would all use the tips of [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).

I don't think tips should disappear after a certain number of reputation points is reached, because the tips are always relevant, and advanced users tend to answer questions, not ask them.

#### Further suggestion (tougher to implement, but very cool IMHO):

Do the above, but write some JavaScript code to detect when it seemed like the tips weren't being followed, and prompt the user to refine the question before posting it.

I don't know if this is the kind of answer you're looking for, but I was about to write my question on this exact topic, and noticed this duplicate. I think it's an awesome idea, and it would save lots of people lots of time correcting badly-written questions.

Comment: A simple proposal for the "Further suggestion" part: If the asker has less than `x` rep (something low in the range 100-250 maybe?), add a checkbox to the tag tips that needs to be checked before the question can be posted. This ensures the user can't just ignore it / is made aware of it - the context sensitive helpers we have atm (similar questions, post preview) seem to often be ignored as many new users aren't even able to format their question _wihle seeing a live preview_. Of course the mandatory checkbox should be removed once the user has sufficient reputation and should know the ropes.

Comment: @l4mpi That's a brilliant idea. Simple to do, but I imagine it might have quite a positive impact.

Comment: For regex tag: Suggest user to add a tool/language tag.

Comment: If it was possible for trusted users to add the tag-spdcific advice (connected to the tag wiki, perhaps), this system would need develiper effort only once, when the feature was added.

Comment: an OOP system of inheritance for tags? sign me up!