# Same answer repeated twice in a question. Flag declined. What did I do wrong?

Tags: discussion, support, plagiarism, duplicate-answers, late-answers

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20486162/2932244) where the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20486179/2932244) was copied and [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33915823/2932244) again by another user within the same question. Do note that the duplicate answer was posted after nearly *2 years*. (Check the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go2nY.png) if answer deleted.)

**Now, I know that this issue has been addressed before in [previous meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274776/2932244).**

But I did what the answer suggested and flagged it for moderator intervention.

[image: Screenshot of the flag]

But then my flag was declined.

My question is what did I do wrong? What should've been done in such a situation?

Comment: The moderator probably mistook the flag as a non-issue. Answering already answered questions isn't necessarily a problem, and moderators are busy, so make sure flag reasons are clear. I've flagged it with the keyword "plagarism".

Comment: "This is copy/paste of existing answer in this question"  would be *much* better explanation. I'd decline flag too given your text.

Comment: Hmmm, come to think of it, use of better words would've helped the moderator. Note to self.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'd be interested to know what the result of your flagging turns out to be.

Comment: @WaiHaLee The Meta Effect will probably delete it first, but we'll see.

Comment: A better way would be to 1. Flag as NAA 2. Comment there stating that *This is a plagiarized answer of <link>. Did you mean to say that the other answer worked? If then, Please do not add such answers*. (The reviewers can understand the reason for NAA by your comment) 3. s̶h̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶a̶t̶ Educate the person who edited the post by asking him not to edit (plagiarized) answers to make them look like legit answers.

Comment: The second answer has been deleted.

Comment: @BhargavRao: A "NAA" flag on there should be declined, since it _is_ an answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'd have flagged as NAA. But if you think so, then "VLQ" would be it. Mod flag is a too heavy flag (imo).

Comment: The duplicate should just be downvoted / delete-voted. A flag isn't necessary. Aside from a mod flag to point out plagiarism, maybe. Plagiarism is serious enough to poke a mod about.

Comment: @BhargavRao - That very same thought came to my mind when flagging it _Does this really require a mod's intervention?_. IMO I think there should be a "Plagiarism" flag. I feel it is pretty common.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro Yep, I think that is better. But the mods need to decide.

Comment: I agree providing good explanation which signifies the flaw in the answers is necessary for raising a moderator flag. I have encountered completely plagiarized answers thrice. I always explained why do I think it is plagiarized, followed by a link to the original answer and answerer's name. All three plagiarized answers were removed.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - I'm surprised! I thought custom flags **had** to be either helpful or declined.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Whoops, wrong flag. It was marked as "helpful" when it was deleted by popular vote.

Answer (score 29):

Personally, I'm a little less optimistic in cases like these:

Since the answer is an exact copy of the code answered ***2 years*** earlier, I'd have downvoted, delete-voted, and possibly flagged it with a "This is plagiarism" mod flag.

The new answer doesn't add anything to the question. It just repeats what the other answer already said, sans explanation.

I wouldn't have used "NAA" or "VLQ" flags: The answer *does* attempt to answer the question, and it doesn't contain any severe formatting issues.

Comment: Good answer, +1 but in rare cases. Another point to add to your "not flag as  NAA, VLQ" is  flagging it as an NAA flag might be declined, because it is possible that the moderator reviewing that flag might not see the other answers. Same for the VLQ.

Answer (score 6):

I would argue that since the code in the first answer isn't massively different to the code in the question, it's not out of the realm of possibility that the the two users came to the same answer independently.

[Code from the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20486162/1364007):

```
$this->db->select('SUBSTRING(zsmonth, 5, 2) as month')
        ->from('tblsales_month');
```

[Code from answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20486179/1364007):

```
$this->db->select('SUBSTRING(zsmonth, 5, 2) as month', FALSE)
        ->from('tblsales_month');
```

Code from (deleted) answer 2 [(link for 10k users)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33915823/1364007):

```
$this->db->select('SUBSTRING(zsmonth, 5, 2) as month', FALSE)
    ->from('tblsales_month');
```

The **only** difference between the code in the question and in the answers is the addition of `, False`, which isn't substantial.

The only difference between the two answers is the indenting of the second line which is indicative of the user copying the code from the rendered markdown (losing 4 spaces of indentation). Either the second answerer was careless when pasting the code (it *was* [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10332178) to fix the formatting) from the question, or from the answer.

Yes, the answers are two years apart and (as I'm unable to see deleted answers) there was only the question and the existing answer at the time the second answer was posted, but it might be worth giving the benefit of the doubt. If there's a history of the same user copying/pasting answers from others (or the difference between code in the questions and the answers are quite substantial and it's unlikely two users produce the same answers independently), *then* I'd probably flag for plagiarism.

---

To answer your question

> what did I do wrong? What should've been done in such a situation?

"This question already answered" is probably *too* vague - moderators have lots to deal with and as others have pointed out, this message you gave your custom flag didn't convey the seriousness of the claim you make.

I would downvote and leave a comment saying the answer is the same as the accepted answer. Something like:

> The code in this answer is identical to that of the [accepted answer](link). Did you mean to signal your agreement with the answer by posting it as a second answer? If so, the right thing to do there would be to either post a comment on it, or upvote it. At the moment you lack the [sufficient reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to do either. Please note that copying/pasting the code of others is [plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268629/1364007) - if this answer is considered plagiarism, it is liable to be deleted.

Were I a 10k user, I'd *maybe* vote to delete the second answer as it's the same as the first (though as I don't have that privilege I don't know what the guidance is for it).

Comment: The 2nd answer was added by a user with 1 reputation. Literally the only thing they have ever done on SO is post that answer. Based on that I believe it's safe to say this is plagiarism, but either way a duplicate answer adds nothing to the question. Thankfully that answer has now been... purged.