# What tags are already supported by how-to-ask tag tips?

Tags: support, tags, tag-tips

Based from [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips), [the feature is already implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/2821954) and it's shown that [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) will trigger it. On the other hand, other popular tags like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) haven't been supported by the system, but might be, as indicated in the same answer.

Now, it seems that only 1 tag is supported at the moment. However, it is [revealed in the chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2588062#2588062) that [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) is also supported (who would guess it?!).

Just for curiosity's sake (who knows, it might create new discussion/feedback for existing tags?), what tags are already supported by this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional tags have had warnings/tips added via the blacklist functionality since Shog's original post. Here is a full list (please update if you find any more):

- [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio)
- [appstore-approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstore-approval)
- [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex)
- [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)
- [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)
- [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo)
- [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)
- [tex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tex)
- [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio)
- [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)

Comment: Ideally, a mod would look into this, since mods have the complete list.

Answer (score 5):

Right now? Just [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).

There is guidance associated with a few other tags... But those tags are *blacklisted* - you can't submit the question if you use them. Currently on Stack Overflow, [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google), [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) and [code-golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) fall into that category.