# What is in the list of Specific Database Engines

Tags: discussion, bug, tags

I posted a question that I tagged `SQL` and `Pervasive-PSQL` I got a pop-up saying:

> ```
> SQL questions get better answers if they...
> Include a tag for one specific database engine (MySQL, Oracle, etc...)
> Show the SQL that isn't working
> Describe exactly how it isn't working (error message, unexpected results, etc...)
> Describe the desired results
> ```

Now Pervasive-PSQL *is* a specific database engine, and I had posted the SQL that wasn't working but I am assuming Pervasive-PSQL is just not on the master list?.

So can we see this list? Can we suggest additions to it? What exactly prompts this pop-up?

Comment: Currently, the SQL tag itself causes the popup. It won't stop you from posting, it's just a prompt to suggest you make sure you have everything. [Here is](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/2607247) the answer where this was implemented.

Comment: @Kendra so even though I have fulfilled all the criteria it *still* pops-up? It shouldn't do that surely.

Comment: Yes- Currently, it's just a test type of thing. The answer I linked to will explain far better than I can. :)

Comment: Not a bug, Matt. To quote the answer I linked _"This'll pop up every time someone tries to ask a question with sql. It's not context-sensitive - if they've already included everything in that list, they'll still get the popup. But, it doesn't stop them from submitting the question..."_ So this is actually status-bydesign.