# For the "Database Related" tags, could we FORMALLY request that DDL for all objects referred to by the question, be provided?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

Instead of:

"I have table "Foo" and table "Bar":

```
Foo
-------
ID  Col1
________
1   "val1"
2   "Val2"
3   "Val4"
```

"

This would be preferable:

I have table "Foo" and table "Bar":

```
Foo
-------
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo]
  (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [clm1] [varchar](15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Foo] CHECK  ([clm1] like 'val%[0-9]%')
  );

INSERT INTO Foo
  (clm1)
VALUES
  ('val1'),
  ('Val2'),
  ('Val4');
```

"

Comment: While I agree this would be helpful, requiring it would be extremely difficult for users.  Many users with database related questions, don't know how to string together a simple select statement, so this could be impossible for them.

Comment: You missed two statement terminators (`;`)

Comment: I always copy these text tables over to the "Text to DDL" converter at http://sqlfiddle.com.  At one point I had started writing a userscript to create them, but then found SQLFiddle already had the functionality.  I'm just happy if they include the sample.

Comment: Even with [heavy prompting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/181965), users still don't even specify their database. Preventing them from posting will likely result in things like php-sql being created or just questions with the incorrect tag associated.

Comment: It's like asking posters to do a minimal amount of debugging before posting their walls of crap.  Time for 'I have a dream' speech.

Comment: I'm a little amused by this request, since, for example, Access programmers can't do this natively and would have to do exactly the same thing you would: go to sqlfiddle or the like. *But hey, Access isn't a "real" database, and those aren't really "enthusiasts", never mind "professionals", amirite?*

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! Some gave a good laugh, some...are kind of depressing about the general mindset of a lot of today's "developers" (or do we still call ourselves "software engineers"? Personally, I've gone back to he "computer programmer" staple"!

Comment: @bluefeet : Completely agree, I'm just asking if some kind of "nudge" could be created if DDL isn't detected, to remind the user that providing it greatly simplifies the possibility of getting more correct answers. I wouldn't want to go all Joe Celko on them, and get REAL bent out of shape, when they don't (although, I understand his aggravations)! 
And would definitely rather questions GET asked, than not at all, I guess.

Comment: @ypercube : Thank you very much, I will correct (I almost wish that, at least T-SQL, would REQUIRE them now, Backwards Compatibility is a CURSE (sometimes....))

Comment: @NathanTuggy : urrite (for the most part). Most "pros" that I know of, that have been blessed by inheriting the "AEA"P"" (All Encompassing Access "Program"), USUALLY use linked data sources, and at least STORE there data in a "more better" storage engine.... if possible. 
Most I know write their SQL in some sort of quality SQL editor, then copy it back. 
But, alas, it IS all but impossible to get the DDL out of Access for a table (which I suppose makes my previous statement moot :) ).

Thank you ALL for your comments!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As someone who is active in the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), I understand your desire to implement this but, if this were required, I foresee issues and can't endorse this request.

Elaborating on my [comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284364/for-the-database-related-forums-could-we-formally-request-that-ddl-for-all-ob#comment146829_284364), there are far too many folks who cannot write simple SQL statements which is why they could be asking questions.  By placing this requirement, we are assuming that they are savvy enough to write DDL statements, and we just can't make that assumption.

How should we define "database-related"?  Will that be based on the tags? Would we say, if the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag is added, then we force them to add DDL statements?  Or if a specific RDBMS tag is added, then we require it?

Unfortunately, users aren't always great at placing the proper tags on questions.  For example, we currently have [2.9k+ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%5Bsql-server%5D+is%3Aquestion) that contain both [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), and I'd guess that the question doesn't apply to both servers.  We have more posts added daily with both tags that need to be fixed because users just don't know what product they are actually using.

If we require this and a user doesn't know how to write a DDL statement, then they could just tag it incorrectly to get the question posted or get frustrated and leave the site unsatisfied.

A solution to this, without requiring it, would be to leave a comment to the user explaining that providing DDL statements would be extremely helpful in answering the question.  Or you could even direct them to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) where there is a nifty little option to convert Text to DDL.  By doing this we are educating the user on how to make their question better, without possibly punishing them for something they don't know.

Comment: Wonder if a "request DDL 'Button' (or whatever)" could be added, that would simply email the OP, something like 

"Hey, it would be easier to accurately answer your question, if you could please add some DDL for the table(s) you provided examples for.
sqlfiddle.com is an excellent resource for this, if you need assistance in creating the DDL

Thank you"

(for that matter, could a link be added that would send the users "SQL" over to sqlfiddle? ((yes, I can be THAT lazy :)  )

Comment: @SteveRowland No need for a button to do that, that's what a comment is for. :)

Answer (score 4):

In full agreement [with bluefeet's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284377/541091), I would also add that ***at least these little text tables tend to be distilled representative samples***. They may not always be adequate, and comments needed to draw out more details, but they're better than posting *too much*.

You'll often find comments in the SQL-related tags requesting a small representative sample of rows from the 2 or 3 tables involved, together with a sample of what the expected query output would be, given those input rows.<sup>1</sup>

Requiring DDL's is very likely to result in giant database export SQL dumps thrown into the question.  Users are *not likely* to trim down those dumped DDLs to something representative and useful any more than they are likely to trim down their problem query to only the problem points.

Routinely (especially in [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) it seems) questions are asked with enormous "code-dump" queries.  A dozen tables and joins involved, multiple levels of aggregation, and the OP having a poor understanding of how the query works overall, to be able to present us with only the troublesome part.  Require DDLs, and with that we're almost certain to get hundreds of lines of irrelevant table definitions.

I've long been in the habit of using the "Text to DDL" tool at http://sqlfiddle.com to spin up quick DDLs from the distilled row samples.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> (That's almost exactly how I usually word such comments)

Comment: I've written that same text in a comment hundreds of times _please include some sample data, table structure, and desired result, etc, etc_, it actually gets a bit repetitive.

Comment: @bluefeet Me too - I dislike pro-forma comments though so I don't mind typing it a couple of times a day.