# Create a warning for UI questions without a corresponding framework tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions

I monitor the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tags, and there is a thing that has become a pet peeve of mine: People asking UI-related questions without mentioning and/or tagging which UI framework they are using.

For C#, there are quite a lot of frameworks (WPF, WinForms, Windows Runtime XAML, ASP.NET, Silverlight, ...) and they share a lot of concepts and terminology. Therefore, it is difficult or even downright impossible to identify the framework in question without being told.

This sometimes leads to the annoying situation where you have to ask for this information in a comment, wait for the answer, and only then find out whether you even know the answer to begin with. Meanwhile, some "fast gun" just guesses the framework and may or may not write an answer that completely misses the point.

Can we try to rectify this?

I propose **the following feature**: If the system detects that a question is about UIs (based on keywords and heuristics?) but lacks a framework tag, display a tip (similar to the [SQL tip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/469708)) that the OP probably should add a tag. We may restrict this feature to some languages/platforms that have proven to be particularly problematic.

Is this a good idea? Is it worth the (non-trivial) effort?

Comment: We need less or better implemented nannying: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300914/posting-link-to-ideone-com-requires-code-breaks-my-answer

Comment: @GEOCHET Well, I am not talking about forcing users to add a tag, only to display a tooltip to nudge them in the right direction.