# Posting link to ideone.com requires code — breaks my answer

Tags: discussion, answers, filtering

I've had to add a dummy code block to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854746/560648) because the answer links to online "compiler" ideone.com.

The thing is, the code under the link has nothing at all to do with the answer: the link serves to prove a fact about the site itself.

Thus, my answer necessarily has irrelevant noise added to the bottom.

What is this restriction there to solve? Can't it be removed, or reputation-limited, or something? I hate to be a naysayer (okay, not really) but this nannying is incredibly irritating and, sadly, on the rise here.

[image]

Comment: That restriction should probably just be lifted if you link to the main site (as you did) instead of to a specific code example.

Comment: It should let you get away with an empty <code></code> block.  Since there's no <pre>, it won't take up the whole line it's on. You'll still get a single grey block, but it's at least the least-obtrusive option until they change this.

Comment: For the record, I recognise that this scenario is an edge case.

Comment: That *should* be how it works already, @Bill - however, it looks like he has a second link that doesn't just go to the home page.

Comment: That's right - I've confused people by having a basic link in there too, but the link to an actual snippet is the problem here.

Comment: @Shog9 Your ping hit the wrong person, BTW. Confused me for a minute until I noticed who'd commented ahead of me.

Comment: @BillyMailman: Alright then!

Answer (score 25):

It might be easier to remove the restriction unless the link specifies an additional path.

So http://ideone.com/ would be OK, but http://ideone.com/anything is blocked.

Should be easy enough to do.

Comment: Please see my code at: http://ideone.com    /anything

Comment: @GEOCHET: This can *already* be used, however notice that this requires extra effort by the user as clicking on the link no longer works.

Comment: You would have to see that error, and then know how the filtering works and then deliberately subvert it; probably a  lot of effort for someone who CBA posting code in the first place :)

Comment: Leading to worse quality. Not better quality.

Comment: Right but the link to ideone.com/something was also problematic here.

Comment: @DaveShaw What's CBA?

Comment: Shorthand for a slang version of "Can't be bothered".

Comment: This is already how it works.

Comment: @Shog9: I love how this answer is already how the site works, and doesn't at all answer the question, but is still highest voted. LOL.

Answer (score 5):

Agreed. The pursuit of having the site cater to the lowest common denominator needs to be tempered by removing some of that nannying for people who have the necessary reputation. In this case, do we not trust someone with (at this time) 166k+ reputation to post a quality answer?

Make this a 'feature' that turns off at a reasonable reputation.

Comment: Disagree: don't disable it depending on rep, change it to not generate false positives as it did here. If a user with >100k rep posts an answer that only links to an ideone snippet, that's still a crappy answer. I don't understand the whole "we can trust people with >X rep not to post bad answers" mentality - there are way too many 10k+ users who post crap all day long (which is how they got to 10k - post a ton of crappy answers to crappy questions and gain rep by sheer volume).

Comment: It could also play havoc with editing. High rep user posts, low rep user tries to edit, low rep user can't save edit until they add code, despite link being part of the high rep user's OP.

Comment: Then reputation means nothing at all. Why trust them with the privileges on the site that we trust them with at all?

Comment: @GEOCHET Devils Advocate, but would you recommend disabling the spam filter for users over a given rep threshold?

Comment: Yes, of course. Why would someone sacrifice a 10k+ reputation account to be deleted as a spammer?

Comment: @l4mip: Spam is malicious. Failing to "bring the content here" and instead lazily linking to an ideone.com post (presumably the use case in mind with this filter) is not.

Comment: @l4mpi: Are you saying, then, that my answer is "crappy"? Because if so then I disagree. And I explained why in this question!"

Comment: @l4mpi: think of it as compiler warning vs compiler error. The post triggers a warning, but doesn't contain an unrecoverable error. Also, eliminating every last false positive is impossible. I think we want to, and can, trust some users to be sensible in ignoring certain compiler warnings. Of course we should improve the heuristics, but fixing bugs and trusting users are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Well, we certainly cannot just go around trusting someone with 166k rep!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm saying your answer is a false positive of a filter intended to prevent crappy answers. That false positive should be eliminated; but that seems to be too weak of an argument to eliminate the filter entirely.

Comment: "that seems to be too weak of an argument to eliminate the filter entirely" -- Who is asking for that?

Comment: @GEOCHET it also seems to be too weak of an argument to disable it for, say, the almost 8k users with >10k rep - see my first comment.

Comment: Who said that 10k would be the mark?

Comment: @GEO Looks like l4mpi is simply rejecting his own proposals ;)

Comment: @GEOCHET who says that you'll find _any_ mark that all people agree with? I'd personally be fine with making Jon Skeet the mark, but that's not very useful. TL;DR: either you make a point for disabling the filter for a significant proportion of the userbase, or it's simply not a good use of SE dev time because it only applies to a handful of users, most of which are never going to run into the problem to begin with.

Comment: That is why this is an open proposal/request/discussion. How do you think any consensus anywhere is ever reached?

Comment: Agreed @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I feel like I am a third party watching someone debate themselves.

Comment: @l4mpi Do note that this is tagged [tag:discussion], not [tag:feature-request] ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit and I agree with the premise under discussion that there are users for whom we could theoretically disable the feature; I simply disagree with the answer as I don't think it makes any sense to actually implement this, given the rarity of the problem as well as the amount of potentially eligible users. Which is basically what you've just added as an answer, +1 for that.

Comment: @l4mpi Teehee :)

Comment: On a recent StackExchange podcast, they discussed the Great Deleting of 2010- when mods with TONS of rep deleted questions by people like the lead dev of C# for very minor offenses which could have been solved with edits.  Even really high-rep mods sometimes don't behave, or are overlyzealous, and people with 100k+ rep aren't really affected by downvotes. so while I like your idea I think it is dangerous.

Comment: What is the proximate harm in allowing high rep users to post a link without code?

Answer (score 5):

> Can't it be removed, or reputation-limited, or something?

Basically… **no**.

This is an edge case, really. The filter is clearly intended to prevent users from simply linking to an example off-site, rather than "bringing the content here". Such links are nice addenda but cannot be the only way to provide a code solution.

In this instance I wasn't providing a code solution at all, only demonstrating as a marginally interesting sidenote that I can *prove* ideone.com's "C++ 5.1" option is in fact C++98.

An easy workaround would have been to inject this proof into the answer, making the interesting sidenote marginally longer.

For such an edge case, this is probably much better than introducing a reputation limit for the filter (or anything else).

Answer (score -3):

Just replace the link with an equivalent one that isn't filtered. For example, any link-shortening service, like Google's.

See [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854746/3538012) now, after my edit. The link works, no `<code/>` section required.

At least, this will work until abusers start using the technique to post links that are of the type meant to be filtered out, and Stack Overflow starts following redirect links to their terminus to determine whether to filter them or not. :)

Comment: *Please* leave all link-obfuscators outside. Thank you.

Comment: @Deduplicator: because, why? IMHO, this is the lesser of two evils. Stack Overflow has a heavy-handed policy to block posts with URLs that take this specific form. Obfuscating the URL bypasses the inappropriate block in a harmless way, and without adding noise to the post (as e.g. an empty `<code/>` section does). Obfuscation can be used for bad purposes, but that doesn't mean all obfuscation is bad.

Comment: Read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257936/auto-expand-shortened-urls and all the others. URL-shorteners (or obfuscators) are a plague.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Uh, huh? That post (and answers), while it does mention some of the harm (I've already acknowledged) can be done with obfuscated URLs, doesn't answer my question. And simply using the word "plague" to describe them also does not answer my question. Seems to me, if Stack Overflow so badly wants to avoid obfuscated URLs, it shouldn't refuse to allow **un**-obfuscated URLs that have a legitimate purpose.

Comment: If you roll that way, then *any* automatic filter for *anything* is ipso facto bad.

Comment: @Deduplicator: that is not a logical conclusion. That a _specific_ type of _broad_ automatic filter has _demonstrable_ harm does not automatically mean that _all_ types of _any_ filter is bad. There is a broad middle-ground available, in which certain kinds of filters are still useful, without unnecessarily preventing legitimate content. Users have _lots_ of other ways to link to off-site code, so frankly, the positive benefit of this filter is questionable, and it has clear negative consequences. And in any case, none of that answers why obfuscated URLs should be prohibited.

Comment: Please provide an example for filters which do not ever under any circumstances have false-positives, and which are still useful.

Answer (score -5):

I agree with @l4mpi that reputation limiting only goes so far:

- Stack Overflow can be gamed, and therefore reaching a reasonable reputation level (say 3k) can be done by sheer volume and a couple of rules of thumb ([fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) helps) in a reasonable amount of time
- Many "old" users (such as myself) have gained their reputation from aging answers and therefore may not be up-to-date on the recommendations
- Humans are failing regularly

There is also another (opposing) issue: the more restricted the privilege, the less usable it is, obviously.

As a result, there is a tension between:

- setting a sufficiently high reputation threshold for it to be meaningful
- setting a sufficiently low reputation threshold so that the ability to *ask* and *answer* is widespread enough

Given that the Stack Overflow system already tends to favor high-reputation users (they must be right, so they get upvotes), it seems that giving them more options to answer might further place barriers in front of newcomers.

---

On the other hand, I find that *preventing* an answer from being posted is too strong.

Why not simply *advise* the user? (changing *must* into *should*, and not blocking)

Potentially, too, maybe feed the answer into a review queue in case the warning is not heeded (so that humans check whether it really is an exception to the rule).

Comment: This implies that all reputation means nothing and that our entire reputation privilege system cannot work. Which is obviously false.

Comment: Advice gets ignored... by *everyone*.

Comment: @GEOCHET: I have tried to explain more in-depth. I find that the reputation system is not a good fit *in this case*; the privileges gained are generally oriented toward *moderation* and NOT the ability to ask/answer. We need few moderators (though could do with a couple more probably), so setting restrictive thresholds that are hard to game works. However, giving high-reputation users the ability to formulate questions/answers than low-reputation users are not allowed to seems "unfair".

Comment: @Matt: Maybe posts that ignore advice should be to the VLQ queue so that humans can examine whether they warrant an exception or not?

Comment: That really makes less sense than your original premise. Yikes.

Comment: @GEOCHET: I remember the forum days where a new user would not be allowed to post a link (to prevent spam), it led to a very frustrating user experience for everyone: the new users had to obfuscate their link and the other users had to reconstruct them. I am afraid that putting SO on this slope is only going to aggravate new users even more.

Comment: SO is already there. This question asks to relieve that problem for trusted people.

Comment: I disagree, I see my own reputation level being reasonable (1.6K), but if this became a feature that unlocked at 3K, I'd be pulling my hair out.

Comment: If what became a feature?

Comment: @GEOCHET: Not quite; this questions raises the issue that this limit is not always warranted, and ask what to do with it: *Can't it be removed, or reputation-limited, or something?*. This answer in the "or something" category, and propose to lower the restriction to an advice (though as Matt pointed out, just an advice might not work).

Comment: Advice won't work, and it is also silly. You trust a user to edit people's questions, flag them, close them, delete them, but you don't trust them to post a link in them? Forest for the trees...

Comment: @GEOCHET: Don't advices also appear during edits?

Comment: Not on basic, elementary concepts of the site and how to use it....