# How can we stop users from using the wrong tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm subscribed to the [`jq`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq) tag in StackOverflow by RSS. For those who've never heard of jq before, it's a command-line tool and programming language for processing JSON data streams. It's a very terse language whose semantics have little resemblance to those of mainstream programming languages, and as such, it generates lots of first-usage questions. I love answering those!

But there's something that I don't like at all. **I really, really don't like jQuery**.

[image: jquery is not jq]
[image: seriously, it is not]

And that's just the first activity page. In case it isn't clear, that's me routinely having to edit jQuery questions whose submitter added the `jq` tag to, replacing it with the `jquery` tag, or, when both are present, removing the `jq` tag.

I'm subscribed to this tag because I want to help people use and learn jq. Not only this is something I enjoy doing, but it also keeps jq's Github issues free of usage questions, so that the contributors can focus on the important stuff.

However, when I spend more time doing tag edits than I do answering questions, it's pretty demotivating.

**Feature proposal:** Would it be possible to, for example, show a message when the user uses the `jq` tag alongside the `html`, `css`, `javascript`, `js` or `jquery` tags, letting them know that they probably don't mean `jq` at all and suggesting they remove it?

Comment: The same goes for Java questions tagged JavaScript (or JavaScript questions tagged Java)...

Comment: Hmya, anybody that starts an open source project and hopes to be successful needs to *really* think hard about the project name.  You can update the [jq] tag wiki and remind users to use the [jquery] tag, that's about as good as it gets.

Comment: There is some code to have warnings when tags are probably not used correctly: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/578411

Comment: @rene: that's great! I'm sure we could use that so that it appears whenever an user uses the `jq` tag.

Comment: Have an upboat just for 'I really, really don't like jQuery'.

Comment: I wonder if `R` has the same problem... So many things start with `R`.