# We don't offer [customer-support] on this website

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There is actually a [customer-support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer-support) tag. It currently has no tag Wiki.

As the FAQ states, [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). That being said, can we burninate this tag?

Comment: "Use in case of uncertainty when requesting discussion, or when the popularity of the tag makes manual retagging followed by automatic culling of 0-question tags prohibitively difficult." Are you really uncertain or those questions are too popular that we would need manual retagging?

Comment: Note that most questions on this tag are NOT customer support questions, but are questions on how to integrate customer support in apps, websites and others. These questions ARE actually on topic (as long as they are specific and meet the rest of our quality standard, which most don't). A quick scan doesn't show any companies using this tag to deliver customer support. There are other arguments why this tag might be bad (overly broad, different meanings in different contexts), but yours isn't a good one.

Comment: The main problem with this tag in my opinion was the lack of a good tag wiki (which it lacks, as stated in your question). I've written up a tag wiki, which is now in the review queue.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The questions aren't hopefully about "generic customer support", but something specific and technical. It is unlikely that we have any "customer support" experts following the tag - it is a tag describing what the question _contains_, not what the question _is about_.

Comment: I would like to add that *all* questions with that tag are closed. So if there is not even one single good question with that tag, it might as well be burninated.

Comment: many companies redirect customers to here. SoundCloud, PayPal, etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Following the ["burnination criteria"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate), then:

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?**

  Not necessarily. Most on-topic questions with the tag seem to be about a specific technical problem not directly related to customer support.
- **and is it unambiguous?**

  No. There is obviously confusion if this was meant to be used for companies' customer support on SO, or for programmers implementing customer support. At any rate it has a broad meaning.
- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

  No.
- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

  No, as far as I can tell while reading through the 43 questions with this tag.
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

  No.

Summary: this tag is a very strong candidate for burnination.

Comment: As I see it, that confusion is pretty limited. Only a small part of the questions are meant to be company customer support questions. And that was before it had a description and wiki, now that it does it will probably be more limited still. I disagree with the point that it's not on-topic, building customer support solutions is very on-topic in my opinion. As long as we make it explicit what the tag's about. If you think this tag will still get misused, we can add a [how-to-ask tip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Even if it doesnt meet the unambiguous criteria, it still meets most of the others. Following your logic that "building customer support solutions is very on-topic" then we should also have tags like [tag:website], [tag:app] and so on.

Comment: Those tags you suggest are very broad, and add nothing to the questions, but you can't honestly say they're off-topic (just because a tag is terrible doesn't mean it's off-topic). Because customer support solutions are more of a niche, the broadness is less of a problem. But yes, it is broad, and it does add little (I even made a weak case for burnination in my first comment). I just disagree with the not on topic point.

Comment: Also, what makes customer support more on-topic than those broad things, is that it usually/sometimes integrates with a larger project. Also, integrated customer support solutions face some unique challenges (such as passing data to the solution from an application that is encountering errors and is in an unknown state), which makes it useful for experts in such matters to be able to follow this tag. There aren't really alternative tags for this.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Even if a question is about building customer support systems, do we actually need a new tag for that? I build H.R. software, but we don't have a [recruiting-system] tag. That seems like a "meta" tag to me (or, at least, unnecessary and useless). Stack Overflow questions [should focus on programming questions, not how to implement the feature as a whole](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: I'm not saying this is a great tag, I'm just saying it IS on-topic in my opinion (and I'm not seeing any strong arguments it isn't, except other on-topic bad tag examples). A meta-tag is something entirely different, such as a [beginner] or a [homework] tag that doesn't describe the problem, but explains a conditions about it. The recently discussed [competitive-programming] tag is another example. I agree with that latest point, that's why I explicitly stated you shouldn't do that in the tag wiki.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It seems really "meta"y to me. How is [customer-support] describing the problem? Good questions should focus on programming, not the feature. I'd similarly object if someone tried to introduce a [recruiting] or [HR] tag - those are things about the feature, *not* about the programming problem.

Comment: Those examples are different yet again. Please try to convince me with actual arguments, not iterating through other bad tags that are somewhat near the problem. The main difference is that a customer support system is (often) part of a program. The other things named here aren't. And let's limit it to the parts we disagree about. I do think this is a bad tag, I just also think it is on-topic, and not a meta tag, because those are quite different. One property of a meta tag (such as beginner or homework) is that you can virtually tag any question with it. For customer-support, that's untrue

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I work on [recruiting] and [HR] software, though. It really seems like creating a [recruiting] tag for my questions would be a bad thing because that's a property of the feature I'm trying to create rather than the programming problem I'm having and good Stack Overflow questions should ask about programming, not features. Something like [java] or [php] are characteristics of your programming question; [customer-support] is a characteristic of the feature you're trying to implement.

Comment: As said, recruiting and hr are quite different, since it's not a common part of a program. I do agree with the fact that it's a feature you're trying to implement, but so are lots of tags (such as [tag:charts], [tag:photo-gallery], [tag:query-builder] and many, many more). That doesn't make them meta tags or off-topic. We can hold a discussion if we should burn all these tags, but for now, that isn't a reason to burninate them, as far as I know. Let's limit this one to this tag specifically.

Answer (score 4):

The community has already handled most of this, whittling down the original 44 questions with the tag to only 32.

I looked through those 32 and found a lot of stinking garbage, so I took it out. Been a while since I saw so many low-quality recommendation questions with even lower-quality answers all in one place (even when the moderator flag queue is included as one of the places).

One or two of the questions with that tag were good questions, and should probably be asked somewhere like Software Engineering (who knows, maybe they already have?), but they are horribly off-topic by current Stack Overflow standards, and they hadn't received any useful answers, so I deleted those, too.

I retagged and kept one of them.

Tag is now burninated; will die a quick and painless death automatically.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, the tag definitely had some absolute garbage questions. Lots of link-only (and otherwise VLQ) answers, too.

Comment: Your flag on this popped up as I was submitting this answer. I don't know how you timed that so perfectly. You must have looked at the tag search results after I finished deleting, but before I finished writing this.