# The [customer] has been removed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I happened upon the [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) tag today.  It presently has 202 questions, 36 of which were created in 2022 (about 6 per month).

The questions, predictably, revolve around eCommerce software.  The top overlapping tags include [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento) (and [magento2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento2), [magento1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento1.9)), and [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce).  In all of these overlapping cases I looked at, while the question asked about customers, the tag added nothing to them.

The remainder tend to include a mix of customer-related programming questions about customer IDs in database queries, customer/client data fields, payments from customers, customer [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) (which may deserve its own thread), and so on.  It is basically [a Meta Tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

While I work for a customer-obsessed company that would frown on lighting customers on fire, I think [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) should be burninated.

An [evaluation of the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/523772):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. Questions are always about something other than customers, who just happen to be the description of the data field the question is about.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Customers aren't much different than the *kittens* example in Shog9's linked post. Neither should be burned. But tags about them... that's different.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

I actually did spend the better part of the last hour looking at all 202 questions.  All those with more than one tag seemed just as relevant to me without the [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) tag.  There were two questions with [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) as the only tag:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71160641/get-diagnostic-information-for-a-computer) is clearly off-topic (asked for recc's) and and would have been better tagged with the already burninated [customer-support tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356660/we-dont-offer-customer-support-on-this-website/356699#356699).
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667887/how-do-i-input-code-into-the-stack-overflow-query-box) has nothing at all to do with a customer.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Not with enough specificity.  Arguably, the concept of "customer" is ambiguous. While most [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer)-tagged questions deal with customers of a business, most of us in larger companies deal with other organizations in the company who are our customers, and there are no Stack Overflow questions about *that*.

Comment: I'm just going to delete that second one with only this tag since it belongs on Meta, is too old to migrate, and I'm pretty sure we have an FAQ for that...

Comment: There's a decent chance this is a stuck tag as well, though we won't really find out until we burn it, and wait for the system to nuke it

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: If the system can't nuke it, but remove it from all questions and bye it goes. This of course assumes that a mod can edit corporate-locked posts to remove tags.

Comment: @Joshua there is a bug that causes some tags not to be removed by the system when removed from all questions.  This is what Zoe means by a "stuck tag."  I'm not sure what you mean about corporate-locked posts, though.  Staff doesn't tend to lock posts on the main site, and in any case I'm pretty sure we can edit pretty much any post.

Comment: @RyanM: It's an old tag. It might have a post locked by Jeff Atwood, which would count as corporate locked.

Comment: @Joshua it does not.  You can check this easily with [a search for `[customer] locked:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustomer%5D+locked%3A1&searchOn=1).

Comment: Of potential relevance, though: it does have a substantial number (69) of locked, deleted spam posts (including several where it's the only tag).  I wonder if that's somehow related to the cause of stuck tags.  That said, this isn't universally true of the stuck tags.

Comment: There's some tags with zero deleted questions, so it's likely unrelated. The bug has already been reported here though: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417362/6296561

Comment: @RyanM: Right now, search for [customer] says there's one question but won't show it.

Comment: @Joshua Which is an indicator it might be a stuck tag. SO is aware, and CMs are on top of it, but sadly not much they can do (beyond blacklisting some tags) without dev time. I'll be pinging a CM if the tag is around tomorrow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Customer support questions remain off-topic, and should be closed
- There are a few questions about e-commerce systems;

  - Questions about existing systems (WooCommerce, Shopify, etc.) can be re-tagged to their respective systems
  - Generic questions about e-commerce systems, or home-made e-commerce systems can be tagged [e-commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) instead, provided they're otherwise about programming
  - Beware of off-topic questions; if it isn't about programming, it should be closed, not re-tagged

## Progress:

The [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=customer),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustomer%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustomer%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustomer%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustomer%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=419137)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 16):

Please don't accept this answer. Accept the completed answer. This was never intended to be a good answer. It was intended to make it possible to vote for burninating the question.

---

Since nobody else posted a "Burn" answer I'm posting a "Burn" answer.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

I mean, it does but not really. It's not a meaningful categorization.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Definitely not. We *do not care* whether or not the question came from some customer of the programmer asking the question. It doesn't matter here.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

As above, we do not care.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

We don't care about distinction between different customer or different department either, so it's actually possible to answer Yes here. I don't care. Burn it anyway.

Comment: "Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? Definitely not. We do not care whether or not the question came from some customer of the programmer asking the question. It doesn't matter here." That could be said about so many tags...

Comment: @DanielWiddis: You're right I probably didn't. I can't always see accept marks.