# The [angularjs] and [angular] tags are constantly misused. How can it be improved?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

AngularJS and Angular are two completely different JavaScript frameworks. Their names are similar enough that they are constantly being misused. The tag descriptions already encourage proper use, but clearly a lot of users just don't read tag descriptions.

Is there a mechanism for mutually exclusive tags? Some sort of bold, hard to miss warning that will be displayed if two such tags are added to the same question?

Would it be better to eliminate the [angularjs] and [angular] tags altogether in favor of their versioned synonyms [angular1.x] and [angular2+] respectively?

What other measures might help encourage proper tag use?

Comment: Merge them all. Problem solved.

Comment: How would that solve anything? They're completely different frameworks. Answers to questions about one will almost never be helpful to similar questions about the other.

Comment: There's been quite a bit of discussion [about Angular et. al](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=angular) - there's not really been much agreement on what should happen...

Comment: While this is a duplicate, there might be a reason to revisit since it's still an actual problem. Since the solution has had it's time, and has been proven to be inadequate, there's a reason to reopen the discussion (and in my opinion, a new question might be the best place for that).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth:  I vehemently disagree that it's inadequate.  Angular is what anyone talks about when referring to the newer versions.  AngularJS is what anyone talks about when referring to the older versions.  I recognize that the tag system itself has limitations when restricting one type of tag when another is present, but I don't see this being so much of a problem that it makes more sense to move the universe from one side to another, as opposed to just *editing out the inappropriate tag*.

Comment: Well, you claim that people keeps misusing them. That would prevent them from misusing them because there would be no way to misuse them.

Comment: @Makoto "as opposed to just editing out the inappropriate tag" well, you know, \*effort\*. I'm basically tired of all this stuff. They don't seem to figure out already.

Comment: How high does the rate of errors need to be to warrant a discussion about lowering the rate proactively instead of correcting the errors reactively?

Comment: @Makoto I was more thinking about adding a [how-to ask tip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips). I'm not advocating radical action, I'm just saying reopening the discussion might be adequate. I see the tags coming round in the edit queue often, but my further experience is limited

Comment: @Braiam:  Pft.  Not a knock on you *specifically*, but generally:  if you don't want to edit the questions with bogus tags here and there, I don't want to help with the necessary retagging efforts.  Both of these things are *effort*.

Comment: @JCFord:  The juice should be worth the squeeze, so to speak.  That is, if either the community or CMs were to take action on this, then it should at least be worth the effort.  Knowing how frequent this is would be ideal, given that (at least for those of us working professionally with these frameworks), there *is* no ambiguity.  I really don't see that many questions asking about an Angular 4+ problem with the tag angularjs, and I don't often see it in the other way, either.  If there's a problem, that's fine, but there should be some kind of evidence or proof that there is one.

Comment: @Makoto I see mistagged questions daily. I admit I don't always edit them. It would be worth seeing stats on how often tags are removed from questions. If these tags are close to normal error rates then so be it. I suspect they're higher.