# Should the [radius] tag be redefined, removed or renamed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The [radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radius) tag refers to two different things:

> RADIUS is Remote Authentication Dial In User Service, a protocol that allows for different management types. It is also a line segment from the center of a circle to its perimeter

[Most of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radius?sort=newest) are using it as the second definition.  So I'm wondering if this tag is really relevant since it refers to two different things, or whether the description should be changed to one or the other.

It came to my attention in the Suggested Edits review queue because a low-reputation user is going through and trying to remove the tag from questions that use it as the second definition, with the comment:

> The tag Radius was referring to the Radius Authentication Protocol. Tag removed

Comment: Maybe rename it to [network-radius] and then remove it from all Q's that are using as the radius of a circle as we don't need a tag for that.

Comment: I like the suggestion, and agree that it is pretty useless as a tag under the second definition.  Renaming, redefining and removing questions for the tag would solve the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  Alternatively, close all questions which refer to the radius of a circle (which are blatantly off-topic) and keep the RADIUS tag, with a cleaner tag excerpt/wiki.

Comment: @Makoto No one reads tag wikis/excerpts so I suspect it will still get misused if the name stays the same.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  The point is to clarify the intent of the tag anyway. I don't disagree that it'll get misused either way, but that doesn't mean we should do *nothing* with it.

Comment: perhaps a [how to ask tip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips) could limit some of the misuse. If we only rename the tag, we either need to blacklist it, or it will likely get recreated (possibly with the circle radius meaning, but will still see misuse)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bradius%5D+-freeradius+-server+-packet+-protocol+-"radius+client"+-radiusclient+-authentication+is%3Aquestion) is a query for [radius] questions not related to the RADIUS protocol

Comment: @doubleDown ironically the first result is about the radius protocol

Comment: @bolov err... that's ... err left as exercise for the reader

Answer (score 9):

**Questions in [radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radius) which refer to the RADIUS protocol should be retagged [radius-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radius-protocol).**

There are already duplicate tags for the concept, possibly attempting to fix the ambiguity:

- [radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radius) (284)
- [radius-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radius-protocol) (22)

So it would be good to get rid of the duplicate tag (even if there weren’t unrelated questions in [radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radius)), and then I’d lean towards the -protocol variant for consistency with DIAMETER, which only has a [diameter-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diameter-protocol) tag.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  Based on the input this has received, should I make a separate burnination request?