# Is there a good way to handle common tagging errors?

Tags: discussion, tags

There many cases where the wrong tag is used: For example, the [12factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/12factor) tag is very common in questions about two-factor authentication (which isn't related).

Is there a simple way to avoid it?

Comment: There do exist [tag warnings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips) but I believe they only operate on combination of tags (or lack thereof). But that is only applicable in a few cases.