# Does forgetting a DBMS deserve a downvote?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, behavior

I left an answer on a question that was not asked in very clear way.

The user did not specify the DBMS and I gave an answer that was correct for [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL). I forgot to add this in the first draft; I then updated the answer to include it, but by that point it had already been downvoted.

I do understand answers need to be clear, but this seems like overkill and will discourage users from leaving answers in the future that are correct, but just need a small edit or note added to them.

The question is linked below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73758559/how-to-replace-a-word-which-comes-after-a-specific-symbol-in-sql/73758607#73758607

Comment: Why not just wait for the question to be clarified before answering? Till it is clarified, go answer some other questions instead.

Comment: "I do understand answers need to be clear but this seems like overkill and will discourage users from leaving answers in the future that are correct but just need a small edit or note added to them." - Yes, That is the intention.  You should avoid answering questions that are unclear.  It does not take much effort to request clarification before you answer the question.

Comment: Boah, VLQ-Question that will probably end up beeing roomba'd, your Answer within 10-min feels like "I post something quick-quick, gimme the Rep...", I find the Downvote justified to be honest... I refuse for myself to answer Questions when FCI (Full Config Info) is not mentioned..., and always mention in which FCI (=> would be at least mentioning the DBMS in "your" Case...) I wrote/tested my Sol... // + This current Question could use a Question Mark in its Title btw, doesn't make sense grammatically...

Comment: But can you not help by giving a possible answer that yes in my case just need to be made little clearer?

Comment: That answer isn't helpful though if they are using a different dialect. Knowing the RDBMS for a SQL question is incredibly important. Even if you supply an ANSI-SQL solution, depending on the product and version it may not work.

Comment: So would it be better to not give the answer even if you clarify the DBMS you are using?

Comment: Define "better"? Downvoting is based on usefulness. I'm no SME, but I can see why your answer may have been considered "not useful" by someone. Them using their votes to indicate that is just the site working as intended. No need to get worked up about the interaction.

Comment: Just trying to determine the best way to answer questions in the future. My feeling is a possible answer would be more useful than no answer but I take the point that if it is the wrong answer it can do more harm than good.

Comment: If the question is unclear, then *don't* answer it; that is the best solution. Then you don't need to make big assumptions like what language/dialect the OP needs, and possibly supplying an answer that is completely wrong for their environment. It takes very little effort for the OP to add the relevant product tag to their question, and saves you and them a lot of time trying an answer that could be completely wrong.

Comment: By DBMS, do you mean the SQL flavour? [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) is not a DBMS. For instance, [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) *could* be implemented by something else than [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server).

Comment: The (R)DBMS the OP is using tells us the dialect they need, @PeterMortensen . For the purposes of this conversation they can be likely be used interchangeably, but the actual product (and version) is more important than the dialect alone. In fact, the dialect alone may not be enough. Both Sybase and SQL Server use T-SQL, as does Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse. All 4 have different capabilities and nuances, with Sybase's being quite different.

Comment: see also: [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/839601)

Comment: *"Does forgetting a DBMS deserve a downvote?"* - that is up to the person downvoting. And I would hope... also depends on the question. If not specifying it makes the question low quality then maybe. I say maybe because me personally I only vote after I attempted communication and gave it a little settling time. But that too is my personal choice, I simply don't believe that doing everything as fast as possible will somehow save the site so I take my time doing everything. Other people think differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this seems like overkill and will discourage users from leaving answers in the future that are correct, but just need a small edit or note added to them

This is a well known problem on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange in general, that the rate of new views on most posts declines exponentially with time, which means that if you get a quick downvote due to some oversight, there is a good change that nobody will see the corrected version and upvote it.

But don't be discouraged by this.

If most of your answers are good, on average the system will reward your efforts. If you care about having your answers upvoted over time, and not just in the first few minutes, the best approach is to try to identify and answer questions that will rank high on search engines. As time passes more and more of your points will come from users searching for a problem and landing on your answer, not by the (few) users that monitor the active list of the tags.

Of course it may be hard to identify the good questions in advance, so try to be helpful to as many people as possible, and don't be discouraged by the occasional downvote. Take it as an opportunity to learn something new if the downvote is deserved.